# Java List - IndexOutOfBounds Exception Error

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

So I am trying to run the below code. But it's giving me the following error:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

```
    public List<String> fizzBuzz(int n) {
        List<String> ans=new ArrayList<String>(n+1);
        
        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
            if(i%3 == 0 && i%5 == 0){
                ans.set(i-1, "FizzBuzz"); 
            }
            else if(i%3 == 0){
                ans.set(i-1, "Fizz"); 
            }
            else if(i%5 == 0){
                ans.set(i-1, "Buzz"); 
            }
            else{
                ans.set(i-1, Integer.toString(i)); 
            }
        }
        
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: `List::add` should have been used instead of `List::set`, the list is empty upon creation.

Comment: Is there any way for me to initialize all the values to 0 when I create the list? @AlexRudenko

Comment: No.  There isn't.  (Apart from the obvious one ... of manually using `List::add` to add a bunch of zeros in a loop or something.)

Comment: `List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[n]);` - this will be a fixed-size list (not an `ArrayList`), with method `add` disabled; all elements are set to `null`